# jquery ui datepicker modification.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

i would like to display some information about the datepicker when input field is clicked. 
something similar to this

[image]

i want to show information about the datepicker where "from" and "to" fields in this image are placed.

i guess the logic applied here is that when clicking the input, it shows a div, inside which is their calendar. but i dont have good grasp of javascript to understand the code. can i get some code examples how this was done with some explanations.
my requirements of datepicker was met from:

http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/11/selecting-ranges-jquery-ui-datepicker.html

thanks in advance.